# How can I use variables from another function in javascript

Tags: javascript

I cant have access to my variables from my function `UserInfo` all my        variables are undefined. How can I have access to my variable and display them in my function `seeInfoUser`

```
let UserName;
let UserAge;
let UserBirthPlace;
let UserDream;  

let UserInfo = function(){
  let UserName = prompt("What is your name:");
  let UserAge = prompt("How old are you: ");
  let UserBirthPlace = prompt("Where were you born: ")
  let UserDream = prompt("What is your Greatest Dream: ");
}

let seeInfoUser = function (){              
  let UserInformation = ` ${UserName} is  ${UserAge} and he was born in ${UserBirthPlace} and his greatest dream is ${UserDream}`
  return UserInformation
}

let result = seeInfoUser(UserInfo());
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are re-declaring your variables in `UserInfo` which causes them to hide the ones already declared in a higher scope.  Just remove the `let` keyword on the variable assignments inside the function so that, instead of re-declaring smaller scoped variables, you use the already declared ones.

```js
// These variables will be available in the current scope and descendent scopes
let UserName;
let UserAge;
let UserBirthPlace;
let UserDream;  
    
let UserInfo = function(){
  // ...So, don't re-declare the variables - just use them!
  UserName = prompt("What is your name:");
  UserAge = prompt("How old are you: ");
  UserBirthPlace = prompt("Where were you born: ")
  UserDream = prompt("What is your Greatest Dream: ");
}
    
let seeInfoUser = function (){
  // You really don't need to declare a variable if all you are going to do is return its value
  return ` ${UserName} is  ${UserAge} and he was born in ${UserBirthPlace} and his greatest dream is ${UserDream}`;
}
    
let result = seeInfoUser(UserInfo());
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue with your code is the scope of the variables. In javascript, all variables declared with `let` have block scope. And you are redeclaring them inside your `UserInfo` function, so you should just use the variables you had already declared.

```js
let UserName;
let UserAge;
let UserBirthPlace;
let UserDream;


let UserInfo = function() {
  UserName = prompt("What is your name:");
  UserAge = prompt("How old are you: ");
  UserBirthPlace = prompt("Where were you born: ")
  UserDream = prompt("What is your Greatest Dream: ");
}

let seeInfoUser = function() {

  let UserInformation = ` ${UserName} is  ${UserAge} and he was born in ${UserBirthPlace} and his greatest dream is ${UserDream}`

  return UserInformation
}



let result = seeInfoUser(UserInfo());
console.log(result)
```